# How to use Transactional Annotation in derived Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I have an abstract Class which acts as Base for all the Beans in my Project.

```
public abstract class BaseBean
{
    /**
     * This method is the template method which executes the life cycle of the
     * Bean. Following is the life cycle for the Bean:- <br>
     * <h1>preExecute<br> <h1>executeImpl <br> <h1>postExecute<br>
     */
    public void exec()
    {
        log.debug("Entering exec method");
        try
        {
            log.debug("Executing preExecute");
            preExecute();
            log.debug("Done executing preExecute");

            log.debug("Executing Service");
            execImpl();
            log.debug("Done executing Service");

            log.debug("Executing postExecute");
            postExecute();
            log.debug("Done executing postExecute");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error("Exception thrown " + e.getMessage());
            throw new ApplicationException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        finally
        {

        }
        log.debug("Exit exec method");
    }

    /**
     * This method needs to be overridden by extending classes and should
     * contain the Business logic for the bean.
     */
    protected abstract void execImpl();

}
```

I have few beans which does Transactional stuff i.e. need to interact with Db and few which do not need any interaction with Db.

**I need my derived Beans to be Transactional** .When I put @Transactional annotation on my Derived Class, it gives “Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread” Exception

But When I put @Transactional annotation on Base Bean, it works fine. I can see in Stack Trace that it adds Transactional Code to my exec Method when I put @Transactional in Base Bean Class.

I want to avoid having my @Transactional in my Base Class since this means all the beans in my project that extend from this class will have transactional Code.
How can I achieve this?
Below is the example of my Bean which gives an error.
If I place this annotation over BaseBean ,it works fine.
My "component-scan base-package=" is properly set to include all the Derived beans.

```
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
public class LoadData extends FrameworkBean
{

    Class tempClass;


    @Override
    public void execImpl()
    {
            List retList = commonDao.loadDatabaseEntity(tempClass);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Using inheritance to do what you're doing is a bad idea: it limits every bean to a single method, and uses inheritance for code reuse rather than polymorphism. Read the chapter about AOP in the Spring documentation, and use that instead.

Comment: Short answer: It wouldn't work on your base bean, either, because proxy AOP isn't applied to method calls on `this`.

Comment: @JBNizet Could you explain what do you mean by "Using inheritance to do what you're doing is a bad idea: it limits every bean to a single method, and uses inheritance for code reuse rather than polymorphism" .I have some common code that I want to keep in Base Class and my whole application some common Code(for e.g messageSource Instance and cacheMgr Instance ). I want my Base class to have it. Any way I can achieve it ?

Comment: @chrylis If i use Transactional Annotation on BaseBean it works fine. When I call  BaseBean.exec(), it works fine.

Comment: It seems that you want to log every method call (before and after), and execute custom code before and after every method call. That's what AOP is for. By using inheritance to do that, you force all your beans to extend the same superclass, and to have only one method always badly named exec(). Prefer delegation over inheritance. Prefer AOP for common cross-cutting concerns (like logging).

Comment: I created an interface containing execute() method.(exec() renamed to execute() in above class). 

public interface IBaseBean
{
   public void execute();
   
   
}

and had my Beans implement this interface also in addition to extending BaseBean
I am calling my beans as IBaseBean.execute() to execute the template methods(preExecute,execImpl & postExecute).Still the transaction is not available.How to proceed?

Comment: @JBNizet.I will add AOP for cross cutting concerns but more than that my derived Class not coming into Transaction is an issue. I implemented an interface IBase to LoadData bean in additon to extending it from BaseBean still it does not find Transaction. If I just implement the IBase interface, it finds it. But i need some extra functionality present in my Base class